# POSIX regular expression for showing line if contains a string

Tags: regex, posix-ere

what is the regular expression for showing whole line if it contains particular string?

source string is "ABC: i am your father" and I need to show everything on the line after "ABC:" so the final output is "i am your father".

Thanks.

Comment: What did you tryied so far ?

Answer (score 0):

This regex will put everything after `abc:` into capture group 2

`^ABC:[[:space:]](.*)`

Input text:  `ABC: i am your father`

Matches:

```
[0] => ABC: i am your father
[1] => i am your father
```

Comment: i think your solution is not POSIX style. for validation go to http://www.rexv.org/

Comment: Sorry, I missed the posix part of the question. On a side note that rexv.org is pretty cool.